# Seeking free high resolution imagery for Las Cruces, New Mexico area

Tags: imagery, united-states

I am looking for a free download Imagery that is a very high resolution and the most recently like the past 3 months.

I'm doing to produce a map where our new building being move into next year.

Is it possible for me to find one online?

Comment: What do you consider to be high-resolution?

Comment: That I need to see the new building took place and need to make a map for other staff to visit to the new building.

Answer (score 1):

Free high resolution imagery, especially as recent as three months, will be difficult to find. I would suggest checking with local and state GIS offices to see if they are willing to release any aerial imagery they might have recently flown.

Commercial companies (DG, Astrium, etc) will not give out their data for free.

Comment: +1 Aerial imagery is your best bet. If there is no recent imagery you may consider some additional elements added to older imagery (e.g. draw in the new building artistically).

Comment: neighboring Doña Ana county https://www.donaanacounty.org/flood/aerial has 2010 aerial imagery for $10k

Comment: Mapperz, The new building would not be in 2010. I need the most currently (2013) the last 3 months. Unfortunely, Radar mention it is impossible to find one.

Comment: tshiffle, Thanks ! What is the normal for us to get the latest imagery ? What I mean that 3 monhts is diffcult to find  so it is better to wait at least 6 months  ?

Comment: Probert - Free high res imagery is always difficult to find. If you are willing to wait a long time, possibly a few years, you can use Google Earth/Bing Maps although its view only. You can't manipulate the pixels.  I recommend contacting an Astrium or DigitalGlobe reseller and having them check the archives for recent imagery over your AOI. With any luck it will be available and you could get it at an archive price of around $25 per sqkm with a minimum of 25 sqkms.